# Stripe with Java Spring RestController - webhook error 404 Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I'm making simple webhook with Spring RestController for Stripe, just to log events, it looks like this:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping("/stripe")
public class StripeChargeSucceededController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/chargeSucceeded", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> chargeSucceeded(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String json) {
        System.out.println("INCOMING TEST STRIPE REQUEST");
        System.out.println(json);
        return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
    }
}
```

I've made test requests to the server with Postman, got 204 accepted response and json logged as expected, but when I'm testing with Stripe I get:

> Test webhook error: 404 Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1

[image]
What am I missing here ?

Comment: How you call this endpoint ?

Comment: @YCF_L I've updated my question with screenshot from Stripe panel.